# How to pass an URL in mailto's body

Tags: html, css, url, mailto

I need to send an URL of my site in the body so the mail recipient can click on that to join my site.

However currently mail client renders the mail like this:

> Link goes here http://www.example.com/foo.php?this=a

The URL is truncated on the `&` symbol, thus the whole process of joining failed. How can I pass the URL like http://www.example.com/foo.php?this=a&join=abc&user454 in mailto body?

My current HTML is the following:

```
<a href="mailto:test@test.test?body=Link goes here http://www.example.com/foo.php?this=a&amp;really=long&amp;url=with&amp;lots=and&amp;lots=and&amp;lots=of&prameters=on_it
">Link text goes here</a>
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You need to encode the URL. This [URL Decoder/Encoder tool](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/) will do the trick. The following [seems to work](http://www.jsfiddle.net/rP9zM/):

```
<a href="mailto:test@test.test?body=Link goes here http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2Ffoo.php%3Fthis%3Da%26join%3Dabc%26user454
">Link text goes here</a>
```

Comment: it will solve any problem related to url so i marked it as correct answer.

Answer (score 11):

I would URL encode the link you are using, so it would be:

```
<a href="mailto:test@test.test?body=Link%20goes%20here%20http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2Ffoo.php%3Fthis%3Da%26join%3Dabc%26user454">Link text goes here</a>
```

Comment: i just tried it. it works! just instead used the first link he gave, not the second.

Answer (score 5):

You can type javascript:alert(escape("YOUR URL")); in the address box of a browser and get the URL made safe for a mailto link. For example, type the following inside the address box of a browser and press Enter.

```
javascript:alert(escape("http://www.example.com/foo.php?this=a"));
```

You will get a message box that will display.

```
http%3A//www.example.com/foo.php%3Fthis%3Da
```

Opera and Mozilla-based browsers allow you to copy the displayed content from the alert box.

You could improve it by typing

```
javascript:alert("mailto:MyEmailAddress@Example.com?subject=My Subject&body="+escape("http://www.example.com/foo.php?this=a"));
```

so that you get the subject and body included in the link. Other improvements could be using a From name and line breaks using %0a.

```
javascript:alert("mailto:Just Me <CMyEmailAddress@Example.com>?subject=My Subject&body=This is the link:%250a"+escape("http://www.example.com/foo.php?this=a"));
```

Comment: thank you for the escape function! This is what I was looking for

Answer (score 2):

as I see  you are using php then you can use "urlencode()" function

```
<a href="mailto:test@test.test?body=Link goes here <?php echo urlencode('http://www.example.com/foo.php?this=a&amp;really=long&amp;url=with&amp;lots=and&amp;lots=and&amp;lots=of&prameters=on_it
');?>">Link text goes here</a>
```