# C#: How can I put clickable link in Mailto body

Tags: c#, wpf, hyperlink, mailto

I'm trying to send email with clickable link in body with mailto. I have been googling and found some articles, but it does not helped me. Same with my problem [Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4710349/how-to-pass-an-url-in-mailtos-body) but accepted answer does not work. There is [sample](http://jsfiddle.net/rP9zM/) you can check quick, when you I click to link it will open new email but link is plain text not clickable.

Here is what I'm trying to do:

```
Process.Start($"mailto:?subject={subject}&body=there should be clickable link https:/www.google.com/maps/place/555");
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: `Process.Start` is used to run a command as a new process in a desktop app. It then looks like you have quasi-jQuery (which is JavaScript for the browser). Without more details, it's impossible to figure out what you're trying to do here.

Comment: @JustinNiessner thanks for your reply, I'm trying to send an email, that contains a clickable link in body

Comment: @JustinNiessner now I'm able to send an email with Process.Start($"mailto: but my link is not clickable it is just like text

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MailTo with HTML body](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5620324/mailto-with-html-body)

Comment: @vesan this is not at all duplicate with question that you mentioning

Comment: @vesan It will be good if you explain me how to fix my problem

Comment: Does encoding the URL work? https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Fmaps%2Fplace%2F555

Comment: @spaceplane no, it does not work

Comment: @Jamaxack vesan is completely right on the duplicate hint. **A clickable link is html** as in `<a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a>`. Everything else would just be a mail program, automatically converting URL strings to links in their non-standard interface.

Comment: By the way: if I use your exact code from the question and just replace the `$` in front of the string by `@` (because C# doesn't like the `$` there) I get your desired result in outlook 2010. As commented, it depends on the mail client.

Comment: @grek40 you are right about email client, now I'm getting what I want in outlook, but in windows's email client it does not work, and about $ this is C# 6 new sintax instead of string.Format()